# apache EqualsBuilder for complex objects

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection, comparison, apache-commons

I am trying to compare two objects with complex structure but apache EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals is failing to compare these two. Can you please tell me what i am missing. It returns false as result.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.EqualsBuilder;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        FirstLevel firstLevel1 = new FirstLevel("string1", "string2", new SecondLevel("line1"));
        FirstLevel firstLevel12 = new FirstLevel("string1", "string2", new SecondLevel("line1"));

        System.out.print(EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(firstLevel1, firstLevel12, true));
    }
}

class FirstLevel{

    String line1;
    String line2;
    SecondLevel secondLevel;

    FirstLevel(String line1, String line2, SecondLevel secondLevel) {
        this.line1 = line1;
        this.line2 = line2;
        this.secondLevel = secondLevel;
    }
}

class SecondLevel{
    String level2Line1;


    SecondLevel(String level2Line1) {
        this.level2Line1 = level2Line1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals` method isn't able to apply the same test of equality via reflection to the SecondLevel class field. You will need to override `equals` (and therefore `hashCode`) in the SecondLevel class for this to pass.

If you can't override equals, and you are happy to add another dependency to your project then you could also look at the `ReflectionAssert.assertReflectionEquals` method in the Unitils library:

http://www.unitils.org/apidocs/org/unitils/reflectionassert/ReflectionAssert.html

Comment: But what if I dont have control over the class ? I cant use extends also because class is tightly coupled.

Comment: You could define an equals method in a test utility class outside of FirstLevel and SecondLevel that tests value based on equality between the two instances of the FirstLevel?

Comment: You could also look at ReflectionAssert.assertReflectionEquals in the Unitils library - I've updated my answer with a link to it.

Comment: thanks Annie. I have 100s of fields in the object and its very complex. Yeah unitils looks promising and it works fine also. But I have apache commons as dependency in my project just wanted to give a try on the apache commons :)